# Why Does my Computer Keep Hard Crashing?

Tags: windows, crash, desktop-computer

This has been going on for the last two years since I've built the PC, and I have tried literally everything I could think of or find online. The computer will crash at completely random times, and when it does, the screen completely freezes. The mouse won't move and not a pixel changes, just instant freeze. Sometimes if I let it sit there for a couple minutes the computer will automatically restart. There is never an error message.

I went through a good period of time where it would only crash every couple of months or so, but now its crashing multiple times per day. I've lost progress on essays I'm writing, and once I had to restart my computer five times in the middle of a 30 minute discord meeting with seven other people. The point is, I desperately need a solution at this point. Here's a list of everything I've tried:

- Reinstalled Windows.
- Tried running Linux Mint.
- Updated every driver I could think of, and used automated software to check.
- Replaced the RAM sticks.
- Replaced the PSU.
- Replaced the CPU.
- Replaced the Motherboard.
- Replaced the SSD.
- Replaced the power strip.
- Checked CPU temperature.
- Checked RAM usage.
- Checked power cable connections.
- Replaces SATA cables.

List of Hardware:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3400G
- Motherboard: ASRock x570 Phantom Gaming 4 WiFi ax.
- RAM: Vengeance LPX DDR4 3200MHz 2x8GB
- SSD: Kingston 240GB A400
- PSU: EVGA 500GD

I don't know what to do at this point, since I've effectively rebuilt the whole computer, and it even crashes on a fresh windows installation. What do I try next?

**Update:**

Well, it has been 8 months and the problem still exists. Up until now I've just had to live with it, but recently the problem has come to a head now that I'm halfway through a machine-learning course for my mechanical engineering degree. The crashing problem has gotten to a point where I literally cannot complete my homework assignment because the computer crashes every time I try to run a computationally intensive python script.

I thought this might be worth adding as an update because I can now reliably get the computer to crash. Paradoxically, I can run a system stress test using AIDA64 with no problem, but specific programs (like a convolutional neural net) are problematics. Before you tell me that this is a specific software issue with the program I am trying to run... it's not. I promise.

Is there some kind of diagnostic software that I can run while getting the computer to crash that will tell me what went wrong? As far as I can tell, Windows saves no relevant info. The computer just locks up, then restarts. The most info I can get back is "Windows was not properly shut down." So, how can I get some better diagnostics?

Comment: You checked the cables but did you replace them?

Comment: You said you replaced everything. Always by parts of the same type? Logically there are three possibilities: 1. The combination of the selected parts doesn't work together 2. There is an external problem that influences the computer like a mobile phone interference which causes the PC to freeze (make sure the case is closed when running) 3. One of the component is not as stable as required e.g. the PSU causes the problems when ever the power grind has slight instability. Reduce your system to an absolute minimum and try to use other may be older parts just for testing.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I didn't replace them. Is it normal for the SATA cable to feel loose? It wiggles back and forth without coming out of the socket

Comment: No; It’s not normal. You replace the SATA device so it can’t be the devices data connector so that leaves the SATA cable since you also replaced the SATA port

Comment: what does this mean? ... `computer will automatically restart`

Comment: Alright, I ordered some SATA cables and replaced the old ones. Still crashes.

Comment: You did mention 'There is never an error message.'  However not too sure if this would be would be relevant but did you look into Event Viewer just in case there was anything logged by Windows just at the time of freeze? What if you do a Clean Boot and check again i.e. running with only Microsoft Services. What if you plug it into another wall socket?

Comment: Are you overclocking the RAM or CPU and is a UDIMM RAM XMP profile being applied? If not, it's either a hardware, driver, UEFI firmware setting issue since reinstalling Windows didn't resolve the issue _(provided you aren't running cracked software, which often comes laden with malware)_. Run the UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics, generally accessible either from within the UEFI firmware settings or the UEFI firmware boot menu; it will default to a Short test that takes >1hr and if it doesn't find anything, run a Long test, which will take several hours.

Comment: Did you check **Windows Event Viewer** for hints?

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Have you verified your [RAM](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/VENGEANCE-LPX/p/CMK16GX4M2B3200C16#tab-tech-specs) is supported with that [motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X570%20Phantom%20Gaming%204%20WiFi%20ax/index.asp#Specification)/[CPU](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-5-3400g) combo?

Comment: After checking Windows Event Viewer, have you ensured there are no power-saving settings in either **Windows or the BIOS** that may be influencing this?

Comment: @JW0914 The RAM should be compatible. I'm not overclocking or using XMP, but I noticed in the BIOS that the voltage was low. Like 2.something instead of 1.35 so I fixed that. Also set the speed to 2400MHz which is what my motherboard recommends for Picasso CPU's and 2xDR sticks. patkim and svin83, nothing interesting in event viewer right now, but I'll check again next time the system crashes. William V, I set my power settings to highest performance.

Comment: @ngatesh Hardware diagnostics are a must since what you describe can only be hardware or motherboard firmware setting related if this occurs on a clean install of an OS _(that by default rules out software/OS issues)_. As to RAM compatibility, I asked because the RAM you're using isn't listed on the motherboard or CPU's specs page _(it's why I provided the links - CPU doesn't support 3200MHz RAM)_

Comment: @JW0914 I don't see any UEFI options for hardware diagnostics, so I don't know how to do that. As for the RAM, I have it set to run at 2400MHz, so it should be fine, right? I suppose I could try getting some different RAM, but the truth is I'm tired of buying new components that don't fix the problem. Also, I know someone running the same CPU/RAM/Motherboard combo and his computer rarely crashes.

Comment: @ngatesh Refer to the PC's/motherboard's manual, as all boards come with built-in hardware diagnostics built into the firmware.

Comment: @JW0914 Here's the manual. I searched for "diagnostic" in the pdf and nothing comes up. Maybe you can find it? [Manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/X570%20Phantom%20Gaming%204%20WiFi%20ax.pdf)

Comment: @ngatesh I would email AsRock tech support

Comment: have you updated the BIOS?

Comment: @Keltari the BIOS is up to date.